# clojure script JDOM2

Tags: java, clojure, clojurescript

I am trying to execute a Clojure script which uses JDOM2, but I am getting the following `ClassNot found exception` on the following line of the script:

```
(import (org.jdom2 Element Attribute Namespace))
```

And the error is:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jdom2.element .....
```

My execution environment path (Windows 8):

```
Environment Variables
       JAVA_HOME = c:\program files\java\jre7;
        Path = c:\leiningen\bin;
System Variables
        CLASSPATH = .;C:\jdom\jdom-2.0.5.jar;
         LIBPATH = C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\jdom\lib;
         Path = c:\jdom;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.7.0_21\bin;
```

Comment: Can you provide your project.clj to see dependencies part?

Comment: I am trying to a third party supplied 'ClojureScript' file which is supposed to convert an input file from one format to another format. I am trying to execute it from Windows 'cmd' line. And as such I was wondering if I am missing any JDOM2 related library from the Paths?

Comment: Yes, but we could see the project.clj we could discard problems, and also check your dependency definition. Also it would be interesting specify when and where are you getting this error